# Postman : How to run some request multiple times and others single time using Postman or Newman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I have three API requests in a postman collection.
I want to run the first and third requests once and the second request multiple times using a data file.

When I pass the data file to the Postman runner it runs all the three requests multiple times based on entries in the data file.

Is there a way to tell Postman or Newman to use data files for certain request only and not all of them.
Or if there is any workaround or a different approach.

Note:- I am refraining from using separate collections for the requests which I will run multiple times as it would become difficult to maintain multiple collections.

Comment: How about iterating the request in pre-requisite tabs of the request you want to run single time or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved with `postman.setNextRequest()`.

Checkout [Building request workflows](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/) for the details.

Comment: I thought about it but implementing something like this will make the requests more complex. This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't see any other possibility.